# How to make a Guzzle post using query string parameters

Tags: post, query-string, guzzle, google-oauth, guzzle6

In a Google Oauth2 implementation I'm trying to exchange an authorization code for tokens using a guzzle call.

The following guzzle call works fine and returns the expected values:

```
 $result = $this->client->post(
        'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token?code=<authorization_code>&redirect_uri=<redirect_uri>&client_id=<client_id>&client_secret=<client_secret>&grant_type=authorization_code')
->getBody()->getContents();
```

However this seems a dirty way to mount the post request.

I've tried the following way in order make it cleaner:

```
    $result = $this->client->post(
        'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token',
        [
            'query' =>
                [
                    'code' => <authorization_code>,
                    'redirect_uri' => <redirect_uri>,
                    'client_id' => <client_id>,
                    'client_secret' => <client_secret>
                    'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
                ]
        ]
    )->getBody()->getContents();
```

However this second call generates a `Malformed Json` error message.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong or how can I debug what final url is being generated in the example above?

Comment: My first guess would be that the requests that are being sent are somehow not identical.  I would start with using the 'debug' request option. Pass in a value of true as an option to the instantiation of your client or within your post request.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I tried without `code` parameter and it worked.

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

$response = $client->post('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token', [
    'query' => [
        'client_id' => '...apps.googleusercontent.com',
        'client_secret' => 'secret',
        'refresh_token' => 'token',
        'grant_type' => 'refresh_token'
    ]
]);

$token = $response->getBody()->getContents()
```

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried using arrays and http://php.net/json_encode